# How to find mean of values over multiple csv files in R

Tags: r, loops, csv, directory, mean

I am trying to write an R function that can loop through 300 .csv files and calculate the mean of columns. Can someone give me high level guidance on how to do this? All the files are in the same directory and have the same column headings. The mechanics of it shouldn't be that hard, but I am having a hard time finding enough documentation on R syntax to do this. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far and describe exactly where you are having difficulty. This will make it easier to help you. It is also the case that your question is awfully similar to a question from a coursera course so searching this site for "[r] pollutant mean csv" should pull up relevant examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to load files into R, but probably the easiest is using the list.files function. Your code would look something like this:

```
setwd("")  # set to your directory
files <- list.files()  #load the file names into the workspace
for(i in sequence(length(files))){
  yourData <- read.scv(files[i])
  yourMeans <- apply(yourData, 1, mean)
  #save your means in some meaningful way from each csv. 
}
```